# How do I stop chrome dev tools from resizing things to fit in the window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Issue: Im trying to see what my site looks like on mobile. Chrome dev tools responsive view is showing a zoomed out version of my website instead of the correct mobile view.

Comment: could you be more descriptive? what steps are you taking to load up the mobile view? have you hard-refreshed? (ctrl-shift-r) what differences are between the devtools display and a real device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

To my index.ejs/html file.